Can I charge multipe 18650 lithium cells at fixed 4.2?
This question is edited.
I am currently working on an emergency light and I want to power it with 4 18650 cells in parallel.
I've tried using TP4056, but that is really slow. It takes well above 10 hours to charge it up. The pack is 8000 mAh.
I've researched about the chemistry of these batteries and found that they require CC-CV modes to charge, and also that charging them to full 4.25 V (ideally 4.20 V) reduces their lifespan. But I've also read that some consumer products use charge-and-run method to charge batteries. Meaning that the battery is only charged in CC mode and charging process terminates once the battery reaches the threshold (4.2 V). This way the batteries do charge only upto approximately 85 percent of their capacity but their life span increases.
Yesterday I charged 3 of them in parallel with a 4.16 V op amp regulator (simple series op amp regulator) with a current limiting and sensing resistor (0.5 Ω), and detected voltage drop across the resistor(through an op amp & both the regulator and detector op amps were in a single IC LM324N) to decide whether the battery is fully charged or not. The charging current kept varying between 0.6 A and 0.8 A and the batteries were cool without any cooling system. Meaning that they didn't get stressed which is a good sign I guess. So should I opt this method and reduce the set threshold to a little lower value for added safety? Like 4.1 V or 4.05 V? I can make sure that the battery won't be left with charger for prolonged periods after charged to prevent plating on electrodes.
Lead acid batteries can't be an option because they are bulky and also take up a lot of space.
Any help or suggestions will be appreciated.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

4.25v ... the symbol for volt is V , so that should say 4.25 V ... also, separate the words, for example, you wouldn't write 3apples

emergency light? Does that mean the batteries maintained at full charge at all times? LiPo not ideal chemistry for that, nickel or lead would be better.

Its not necessary to keep the battery topped up all the time. Instead, I prefer a shorter runtime and longer life span. I've found out that some consumer products charge batteries in charge-and-run manner. Meaning that the battery is only charged in CC mode and charging is terminated as the voltage threshold is reached (typically 4.2 V) and saturation charge (CV mode) is not provided. This charges battery upto 85 percent of its capacity but provides longer life span.

The simple answer is to get a suitable sized Lithium battery charger. What you are attempting is a poor approach for charging Lithium batteries - the charge profile is more complicated and they don't like to be left on a float charge.
Have you considered using 4 tp4056 (one for each cell) and diode OR'ing the 4 cells? This will cut your charge time down to 2.5hrs.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

Can you elaborate on the diode OR method for the 4 cells please?  Maybe a quick schematic?

@anon33 you ask and you shall receive.

Thank you.  Interesting stuff; I suppose it would be good to choose diodes with a low forward voltage drop, like a schottky perhaps?

@anon33 Ideally, yes. But for a lighting application where a precise voltage doesn't matter (especially when you consider the battery voltage over it's discharge cycle and also your LEDs will have a regulator to compensate anyway), I wouldn't bother. You can get those 4 diodes in a single 8-SOIC package for cheap.

@anon33 If the voltage lost to the diodes did matter, there are ways to manage that as well with additional circuit complexity.
